# how to remove an element and those who depend on it with codeIgniter 4

Tags: codeigniter

When I delete the element it deletes all the element that depends on it but also the element that it depends

Here is my code

```
public function deleteData($id_entite = null)
    {
        $session = \Config\Services::session();
        if($id_entite != null){
            $model = model(Prsai_EntiteModel::class);
            $entitefils =  $model->getEntiteByParent($id_entite);
            foreach ($entitefils as $une_entite) {
                $model->delete($une_entite);
           }
            if($model->delete($id_entite)){
                $session->setFlashdata("success_delete","OK");
                return redirect()->to(base_url('entite'));
            }
            else{
                $session->setFlashdata("error_delete","NO");
                return redirect()->to(base_url('entite'));
            }
    }
```

To find dependencies

```
public function getEntiteByParent($id_entite)
    {
        $resultat = array();
        $entites =  $this->where(['id_parent' => $id_entite])->findAll();
        foreach ($entites as $une_entite) {
            //var_dump($une_entite);
            $une_entite['nb_sous_entite'] = $this->getEntiteNbSousEntite($une_entite['id_entite']);
            $resultat[] = $une_entite;
        }

        return $resultat;
    }
```

To find dependencies

```
 public function getEntiteNbSousEntite($id_entite)
    {
        //$query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM my_table');

        //echo $query->getNumRows();
        return $this->where(['id_parent' => $id_entite])->countAllResults();
    }
```